# Java Thread not starting?

Tags: java, multithreading, datagram

```
package BroadCast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Server extends Thread {

    private DatagramSocket sock;

    public static boolean ServerUp = false;

    // Wierdly not running this as a thread.
    private void Server() {
        try {
            sock = new DatagramSocket(Constants.port);
            ServerUp = true;
            // Prints on console.
            Constants.Server(Constants.ServerName
                    + ", loaded sucessfully on port: " + Constants.port);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (ServerUp) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket Packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                sock.receive(Packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Prints on console.
            Constants.Server(new String(data).trim());
        }
    }

    public void ServerData(byte[] data, InetAddress ip, int port) {
        DatagramPacket Packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ip, port);
        try {
            sock.send(Packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the main void for my Server class, and it didn't have an output (Like it's suppost to). But when I put:

```
new Server().Server();
```

(to run the Server void), it worked. But, It won't loop correctly (Like a normal thread would).
If you could help me, that would be great (it's probably a minor mistake).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that, confusingly,

```
private void Server() {
```

declares a method called `Server` **and not a constructor**.

To turn it into a constructor, remove the `void`:

```
private Server() {
```

Once you've done this, `new Server().start()` should work.

Comment: @Mr.Charles: It is subtle error. I've seen it before, and I am surprised that compilers don't warn about this.